# Bot Framework- Why Choice hold CardAction, and what is the role of each?

Tags: c#, botframework

I use *Bot Framework v4*, and I try to use `ChoicePrompt` for the menu.

I'm trying to create a `Choice` object, and I see that it contains a `CardAction` object.

Because `CardAction` has more options, such as a `value` that is an `object` type rather than a `string` type, I want to use it.

But even if I assign a value to the `CardAction` `value` field, I get an **error** because `Choice` must get a value in its `value`, which is the value obtained **at the end**.

So why does the `Choice` contain a `CardAction` object? What is everyone's job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `CardAction` Object

There isn't really any documentation on using `CardAction` with a `ChoicePrompt` because `ChoicePrompts` aren't really "meant" to be used this way. It's possible, but not really preferred.

[Here's the reference for the `CardAction` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.cardaction?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable):

**DisplayText**
Gets or sets (Optional) text to display in the chat feed if the button is clicked

**Image**
Gets or sets image URL which will appear on the button, next to text label

**Text**
Gets or sets text for this action

**Title**
Gets or sets text description which appears on the button

**Type**
Gets or sets the type of action implemented by this button. Possible values include: 'openUrl', 'imBack', 'postBack', 'playAudio', 'playVideo', 'showImage', 'downloadFile', 'signin', 'call', 'payment', 'messageBack'. [More on ActionTypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.actiontypes?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable)

*Note: ChoicePrompt expects a `imBack` ActivityType, so using other types can have some odd results.*

**Value**
Gets or sets supplementary parameter for action. Content of this property depends on the ActionType

#### Title vs. Text

Given the `CardAction`:

```
new Choice()
    {
        Action = new CardAction()
        {
            Type = "messageBack",
            Value = "ACTION VALUE",
            Title = "TITLE",
            Text = "TEXT",
        },
        Value = "CARD VALUE",
    });
```

This will produce:

[image]

When clicked:

[image]

So, `Title` is the text displayed on the button. `Text` is the text send back to the bot as a message. If `Value` is present in the `CardAction`, it gets sent as the activity's `value`.

#### The Bug

I see that you [submitted this question to GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/1485), as well. I'll just duplicate the response here.

The issue isn't so much that you can't have a null `Choice.Value` so much as when extracting `Choice`s from the `CardAction` and trying to determine the max length of the text to display for the Choice, `ChoiceFactory` was incorrectly looking at `Choice.Value` while it's null instead of looking at `Choice.Action.Title`. See [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/pull/1503) for the fix, there.

Comment: My question is based on many false assumptions. Probably because the framework is partly documented and written strangely. (My opinion)

Comment: No problem. This is getting off-topic a little, but if you want to use cards in ChoicePrompts, you might want to read [one of my other SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55066910/10860086)

Comment: I forgot something. Can you explain the difference between `Text` and `Title`?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an explanation. See "Title vs. Text"

Comment: "ChoicePrompt expects a messageBack ActivityType", actually didn't work for me, but with `postBack` works

Comment: Good catch. It should actually be `imBack`. Be aware that `postBack` is not supposed to show in the chat window, so this may be undesired for some. I also had the wrong link in there for `ActionTypes` and have edited it.

Comment: Yes, I saw the wrong link, but I could not find the right one :)